# HTML5 show pdf embedded

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

In my application I show a pdf embedded in my browser page in this way:

```
    <div>
        <object ng-if="vm.ShowPanel" data="{{'data:application/pdf;base64,'+ vm.URL}}"
                style="width:100%; height:99%; overflow-y:hidden" type="application/pdf"></object>
    </div>
```

This approach works perfectly in Chrome but as known not in Internet Explorer.

Is there a workaround to perform that action in IE?

I was thinking about saving the file locally and then read it in my object tag.

Could it work?

thanks

Comment: it only works in Chrome because Chrome has an extension built-in which can display PDFs. I'd guess it would work in Firefox too. But IE has no such support built-in. The user would have to install a suitable plugin.

Comment: @ADyson yes I know that. But I know that you can open a local pdf file in IE with an <iframe> for example. My question is if there's a way to store the PDF file in a temp directory and then open it programmatically

Comment: No, because you don't have access to the local disk (think of the security implications if you did - anyone could download all sorts of unpleasant stuff to your drive). If you simply ask the user to download the file in the conventional way, you've no control and no way of knowing where they stored it, so you can't rely on that either. You either just offer the download, or you suggest to them to install a plugin and hope they do.

Comment: @ADyson And using the localStorage of the browses do you think is a bad idea?

Comment: You could put the file there, sure, but it doesn't change the fact that the browser doesn't know how to display it. I doubt that the `<iframe>` idea would work, because you haven't got a hard-disk file reference to point the iframe at. By all means try it, though.